# Printing Paths for Trees

Tags: java, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, binary-search

```
   static void printAllPathsFromRootToLeaf (BinaryTree<Integer> tree, ArrayList<Integer> path)
{
    if (tree.isEmpty())
    {
        System.out.println("Tree is Empty");
        return;
    }
    path.add(tree.root());

    if (tree.left().isEmpty() && tree.right().isEmpty())
    {
        System.out.println(path);
        printSum(path);
        //return;
    }
    else
    {
        printAllPathsFromRootToLeaf(tree.left(),new ArrayList(path));
        printAllPathsFromRootToLeaf(tree.right(),new ArrayList(path));
    }
}
```

When print the path it only prints the last path or it only prints one path in my tree. Would anyone know why??

THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it only prints the last path or it only prints one path in my tree

This is because you have choosen it to do so with this line:

```
if (tree.left().isEmpty() && tree.right().isEmpty())
```

AKA if the Node is a leaf Node, print it.

Add this to the else statement

```
else
{
    System.out.println(path); //Not exactly sure what printing an ArrayList like this does, but you say it is doing what you want.
    printSum(path);
    printAllPathsFromRootToLeaf(tree.left(),new ArrayList(path));
    printAllPathsFromRootToLeaf(tree.right(),new ArrayList(path));
}
```